# Clojure "is" assertion not working as expected

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, functional-programming, clojure-testing

I am writing test cases for my first Clojure project. Here, I want the test to fail if the value of ":meat" is empty :

```
(deftest order-sandwich
  (let [response {:meat "" :bread "yes" :add-on "lettuce"}]
    (is (= (:bread response) "yes"))
    (is (not (nil? (:meat response))))))
```

But my test runs successfully (returning "nil") .

Anybody know why this happens? Is there a better way to do this?

I thank you in advance!!

Comment: Thank you @AlanThompson for the edit.!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An empty String is not `nil`:

```
(nil? "")
=> false
```

You want to test if it's empty, not `nil`, which can be done using `seq` or `empty?` (among other ways):

```
(is (not (empty? (:meat response))))
; Or use not-empty

; There's also the arguably more idiomatic way

(is (seq (:meat response)))
```

Comment: Thank you @Carcigenicate for the input, that works!

Comment: @SnehaaGanesan No problem. Glad to help.

Comment: (is (= false (empty? (:meat response)))) works too !!

Comment: @SnehaaGanesan Yes. It's often not advisable to check against `true`/`false` though. That would be like in Java doing something like `if(someVar == true)`. It's redundant. You might as well just write `if(someVar)`, or `if(!someVar)` if you need it negated.

Comment: @SnehaaGanesan also relevant: like the empty string zero is truthy in clojure which can throw people coming from various languages where that's not the case.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I see, thank you for the explanation!!

Comment: You may also use `not-empty`: 
`(is (not-empty (:meat response)))`

Comment: @JurajMartinka Added.